# ruby call to method within while

Tags: ruby, methods, while-loop

I have 2 Models : Book and Author. They both are habtm in relation to each other.

Model Author looks like this :

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :books
    def full_name
        given_name + " " + nom # For ease of select menu in the form
    end
end
```

In the controller, this piece of code creates the entry into books and into the join table :

```
z = Author.find(a[0])
z.book << @book
```

I put that piece of code in a while loop, like this :

```
i = 0
lettres = ("a"..."z").to_a
while i < a.count
  lettres[i] = Auteur.find(a[i])
  lettres[i] << @biblio
  i += 1
end
```

The reason why I do this way, is because a book can have upto 20 authors. `a` is the array that contains the author ids.

This causes an NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `<<' for #<Auteur:0x007fd61ab20618>
```

I don't understand why, as when testing classes and call to methods in the class, it does work in a while loop. So this **does work** well :

```
lettres = ("a"..."z").to_a
i = 0
while i < t.count
    lettres[i] = Blabla.new(t[i])
    lettres[i].sound
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: Please, add to your question how model `Auteur` is looks like

Comment: This error tell you that your model Auteur don't have method <<. As I understand Auteur- is a Author and @biblio is a book?

Comment: yes, correct. But when I run that code from outside the while loop, than it works fine.

Comment: (yes I did translate for the ease of understanding)

Comment: `lettres[i].books << @biblio`

Comment: @thiebo: your code outside of the loop is different from what you run in the loop. The one in the loop has a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to use `lettres` at all, so you could remove it.

Also, if `a` contains `Auteur` ids, just call it `auteur_ids` :

```
@auteurs = auteur_ids.map do |auteur_id|
  auteur = Auteur.find(auteur_id)
  auteur.books << @biblio
  auteur
end
```

If `auteur_ids` size is smaller than 26, you'd get an Array with a mix of Auteurs and letters.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so, as you can see, when you try to add book to your author out of loop, you call method `.books` so,

```
i = 0
lettres = ("a"..."z").to_a
while i < a.count
  lettres[i] = Auteur.find(a[i])
  lettres[i].books << @biblio
  i += 1
end
```

- should work.
 - List item

Also I will recommend you edit your code to:

```
a.each_with_index do |id, index|
  lettres[index] = Auteur.find(id)
  lettres[index].books << @biblio
end
```

Comment: Yes, and also ditch the `while`, you can use `.map`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I think, `each_with_index` in this case looks better :)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: Nope, it doesn't. Read the code closely. It replaces original array content with author objects, which are derived from the elements. That's mapping in disguise.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, but you can see here 2 arrays, one with `ids` of these authors and array that we should replace with authors, so, better way for this case is work with `array` with`ids`, nope?

Comment: @thiebo if your answer was solved, mark like right answer, please, for viewers that come here to look at solution)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: huh? There's only one array here. And that's bad, IMHO (when variables suddenly change their type). If it were me, I'd have `author_ids` and `authors` arrays. Or if you do want to recycle the array, you can either do `authors.map!` or `authors = authors.map`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeap, two :) First from code: `lettres = ("a"..."z").to_a` and second from author comment: "`a` is the array that contains the author ids."

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: indeed! Still, it changes nothing, because in this case, contents of `letters` are simply ignored, so we can just do `letters = a.map`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I understand, what you want to tell, but if author create these two arrays, maybe, he also used them in others cases that he will close from us :)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko: somehow I doubt that there's a hidden reason for this. But ok, I hear you. :)

Comment: Maybe I should clarify : there are 2 arrays. The first array contains the author ids and the second array simply contains the letters of the alphabet. The second array has only one purpose, which is to instantiate and hold Author.find(id[i]) and then to call method `.books` on that instance. I hope this helps in understanding what the code does.

Comment: @thiebo: wat? You don't need a temp array of letters to create an array of authors. That part is super-weird.

Comment: @thiebo: you should be always able to accept answers to your questions. Maybe upvote too. Although it's been a while since I was 1 rep :)